# My mobile css isn't working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My mobile css hamburger menu isn't working, if I click on it it doesn't stay open, and I have no clue on how to open the dropdown menu inside the hamburger menu. Also my nav title (.logo) is hard to center, does anyone have a solution for that?

[JSFidlle for easy viewability](https://jsfiddle.net/7xjyutuf/8/) (Mobile css & Style.css in are merged here only the background is missing)

Thanks for any help, and sorry if my code looks messy :/

My Code:

Index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello, I'm Sten</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="nav animated slideInDown">
       <img src="img/hamburger.png" alt="" class="hamburger">
       <div class="logo">
          <h1>STEN</h1>
       </div>
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="#">PAGE</a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">DROPDOWN</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="landing animated fadeIn">
       <div class="container">
            <h1>STEN</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>I'M A</p>
            <h2>-OCCUPATION-</h1>
            <button>KNOP</button>
            <button>KNOP</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll" onClick="">

        </div>
   </div>

   <div class="about">

   </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Style.css (Master css file)

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.nav .hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.nav .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.nav .logo h1 {
    color: #000;
    line-height: 10vh;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.nav > ul {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;

}

.nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

.nav > ul > li:first-child > a:after {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: calc(5vh - 5px);
    margin-left: 8px;
    content: "";
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    margin-left: -50%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.nav ul a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 10vh;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #999;
}

.landing {
    padding-top: 10vh;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    z-index: 0;
}

.landing:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.landing .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
}

.landing .container h1 {
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    font-size: 78px;
}

.landing .container p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.landing hr {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 150px);
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EF2D56;
}

.landing button {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 24px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.landing button:first-child {
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.landing button:last-child {
    margin-left: 1%;
    background-color: #EF2D56;
    border: 1px solid #EF2D56;
}

.landing button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.landing button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.scroll {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 8px);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.about {
    height: 200%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;;
    z-index: 50;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

Mobile css file

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 850px){
    .nav .hamburger {
        height: 6vh;
        width: 6vh;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin: 2vh 0 0 2vh;
    }

    .nav .logo {
        position: relative;
    }

    .nav > ul {
        display: none;
        float: none;
        margin-top: 10vh;
    }

    .nav .hamburger:hover ~ ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .nav > ul > li {
        display: block;
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
    }

    .about {
        margin-top: 100vh;
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears to require a `hover`, since you can't hover with a finger (at least, not in a way the device can read) it's not going to remain open.

Answer (score 1):

Change the way you wrote media query, Try this way:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    //Your mobile CSS code
}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7xjyutuf/1/

Comment: This fixes some things, but the hamburger menu still isn't static and dissapears after clicking it.

Comment: Can you explain the way you are expecting the hamburger should work?

Comment: If I click the hamburger menu on chrome, the nav shows up, but when I try to click a link it dissapears. I would like for it to stay there so I can click a link. 

And a minor problem is I need to have the dropdown menu inside the nav to drop, and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Please add your js code what you did for the clicks/hover!

Comment: I got this now: https://jsfiddle.net/7t2pvy3h/2/ , I didn't use any js. Only thing i want to change is that the ul is 100% width and make the dropdown inside the nav working, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

chnage your media query into this `@media only screen and (max-width:850px){}`.

1. If you are using the `max-device-width`, when you change the size of the browser window on your desktop, the CSS style won't change to different media query setting;
2. If you are using the `max-width`, when you change the size of the browser on your desktop, the CSS will change to different media query setting and you might be shown with the styling for mobiles, such as touch-friendly menus.

for more info you can visit this http://www.menucool.com/3613/max-device-width-vs-max-width-Which-one-should-I-use

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ok7hmodo/1/

For making the menu static use Jquery.Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/7xjyutuf/10/.

This is a css only solution.You have to make the  ul display block when user hovers on it 
https://jsfiddle.net/tucsgohy/1/

Comment: I changed it to max-width, and it's easier for testing etc, but it doesn't fix my main problem; the hamburger menu still isn't static

Comment: I got this now: https://jsfiddle.net/7t2pvy3h/2/ , I didn't use any js. Only thing i want to change is that the ul is 100% width and make the dropdown inside the nav working, any ideas?

Comment: remove position absolute form the ul  .https://jsfiddle.net/enuggdqf/3/ check if this works